# In SQL Management Studio 2005 can I generate JUST the constraints and indexes ALTER SQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

In SQL Server 2000 Enterprise Manager when someone used "Generate SQL Script" on a database it was possible to untick "generate the CREATE command ..." and "generate the DROP command ..." option and then tick the "Script indexes" "Script Full Indexes" etc. This would generate a script filled with ALTER TABLE commands (assuming the database had tables with indexes and constraints).

My problem is that in SQL Management Studio for 2005 (and I think 2008) this ability seems to have disappeared. When I chose not to generate the CREATE scripts but tick all of the options for indexes etc. it generates a blank file.

Am I missing something in the options??

Can anyone help?

Cheers,

Niko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that option seems to have been retired. You will have to generate them yourself using a script. Several examples exist on the web: [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/Miscellaneous/31893/)

There is also a utility here that looks like it will work for you as well:  [link](http://sqlsrvscrpt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DBScript%20Utility&referringTitle=Home)